# URL can't be opened from the application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, browser, uiapplication

In an application, this:

http://web.extebtion/projects/projectName/myaccount.php?1310625280.37+TE1PUFha-MDEyMzQ1Njc4OV85X3NpbXVsYXRvcg==+1310625280.37

(TYPE OF) URL is being tried to open by:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:http://web.extebtion/projects/projectName/myaccount.php?1310625280.37+TE1PUFha-MDEyMzQ1Njc4OV85X3NpbXVsYXRvcg==+1310625280.37]]];
```

line of code, but, this line doesn't open the URL in iPhone browser. But if **==** is being removed from the URL, all problem get solved.

Now the question is, **How to check if the browser have opened a URL or not**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to just specify the `@"<string>"`, i.e.:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://web.extebtion/projects/projectName/myaccount.php?1310625280.37+TE1PUFha-MDEyMzQ1Njc4OV85X3NpbXVsYXRvcg==+1310625280.37"]];
```

You'll know the browser opened the URL, because Safari will pop into the foreground and load the URL.

Comment: Well it doesn't actually helped, but thank you for the response. :)